# autocomplete jquery и полноэкранный режим

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, autocomplete

Здравствуйте! Для реализации полноэкранного режима использую javascript, вот код:

```
    var fullScreenElement = document.getElementsByClassName("contentCenter")[0];
    if(fullScreenElement.requestFullScreen) {
        if(!document.fullScreen) {
            fullScreenElement.requestFullScreen();              
        } else {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        }
    } else if(fullScreenElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        if(!document.webkitIsFullScreen) {
            fullScreenElement.webkitRequestFullScreen();                
        } else {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        }
    } else if(fullScreenElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        if(!document.mozFullScreen) {
            fullScreenElement.mozRequestFullScreen();   
        } else {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        }
    }
```

Внутри `<div class="contentCenter">` есть поле для автокомплита, которое реализовано через jquery autocomplete. При вводе текста плагин отображает `<ul>` элемент с вариантами для выбора. Проблема в том, что он вставляется не во внутрь `<div class="contentCenter">`, а прямо в `<body>`. При полноэкранном режиме `z-index`, с помощью которого реализовано выплывающее меню поверх всех остальных элементов не работает и его просто не видно. Подскажите, как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил добавлением всех `<ul>` элементов в тот DIV, который разворачиваю на полный экран.